# jQuery mobile loading script after submitting form to self

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am writing a processing script that allows users to enter data in compartments on a form and save each section rather then complete the whole page in one go. It is essentially a sequence of forms within expandable elements within the page. However, Upon submitting any form to itself, the page cannot reload any javascript, In the documentation for jquery mobile it does say this can be problematic but I cant make any of the solutions offered there work.

I've stripped my code down to a very basic skeleton for troubleshooting:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload = myFunction("<?php echo $_GET['p']?>")>
<script>

function myFunction(tab)
{
$('#content_'+tab).collapsible('expand'); 
}
</script>
    <div data-role="collapsibleset" class="ui-content">
        <div id = "content_1" data-role="collapsible">
            <h1>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h1>
            <form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?p=1"?>" method="GET">
                <div><input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Save"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id = "content_2" data-role="collapsible">
            <h1>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h1>
            <p>I'm the expanded content.</p>
        </div>
        <div id = "content_3" data-role="collapsible">
            <h1>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h1>
            <p>I'm the expanded content.</p>
        </div>
        <div id = "content_4" data-role="collapsible">
            <h1>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h1>
            <p>I'm the expanded content.</p>
        </div>
        <div id = "content_5" data-role="collapsible">
            <h1>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h1>
            <p>I'm the expanded content.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is trying to accomplish a simple task. When a form is submitted, send it to itself, where some php script will process the results and the page will then load the updates into the form fields. This all works perfectly, the section that isn't doing what it is supposed to is the myFunction process that should set the active expandable content to the value of content_(what ever number is in $_GET['p']).

I thought having it in body would force its update on page load but jquery mobile acts differently.

I've also tried having the js in a separate .js file loaded in the header to no avail.

I've even tried including all the java script inside a div element  and using that wrapper around all the expandable content elements as the jQuery documentation says (i think) that only div elements are loaded.

when a form is submitted it is processed but no content is auto-expanded. If you manually refresh the page it expands as it should but you shouldn't need to manually refresh the page after clicking save.

ive also tried using

```
  <script>
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", function( event ) {
    var tab = <?php echo $_GET['p'];?>;
    alert(tab);
$('#content_'+tab).collapsible('expand');
});

</script>
```

This above will echo the correct value of p, but wont assign an expand to anything. I tried including it before and after the div elements that are expandable.

I'm running out of ideas to try and make it load, am i missing something simple or is there an alternative that I've just not come across yet?

Comment: Can you please create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of the problem?

Comment: I cant, it wont allow me to enter any php code which is how this sends data. Even omitting the php, it wont load the jquery mobile for some reason.. Ive never used jsfiddle before though to Im probably doing it wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in your pagecontanershow event and then putting a switch to run script based on the page that is loaded.  Remember that when using AJAX navigation that JQM only loads the body of the second and subsequent pages, JS loaded from the header is only loaded on the first page load so you need to make it all available then.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function(event, ui) {

console.log('pagecontainershow::navigating to page ' + ui.toPage.attr('id'));

page_id = ui.toPage.attr('id');


switch (page_id) {
case 'page-id1':
    //some page specific code here
    break;
case 'page-id2':
    //some more here
    break;
}
});
```

Comment: Im sorry but im not able to follow the syntax too well in the above. I entered it as a stand alone function but I am not sure how the variable 'id' is attained, when I output it as it stands its undefined. My code should always redirect back to itself, the only change to the url will be hte ?p= variable at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how technically correct this is, but it works and includes very little alteration.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload = myFunction("<?php echo $_POST['p']?>")>
<script>
function myFunction(tab)
{
$('#content_'+tab).collapsible('expand'); 
}
</script>

<div data-role="collapsibleset" class="ui-content">
    <div id = "content_1" data-role="collapsible">
        <h1>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h1>
        <form data-ajax="false" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
            <input type = "hidden" name = "p" value = "1">
            <div><input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Save"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id = "content_2" data-role="collapsible">
        <h1>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h1>
        <form data-ajax="false" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
            <input type = "hidden" name = "p" value = "2">
            <div><input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Save"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id = "content_3" data-role="collapsible">
        <h1>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h1>
        <form data-ajax="false" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
            <input type = "hidden" name = "p" value = "3">
            <div><input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Save"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id = "content_4" data-role="collapsible">
        <h1>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h1>
        <form data-ajax="false" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
            <input type = "hidden" name = "p" value = "4">
            <div><input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Save"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id = "content_5" data-role="collapsible">
        <h1>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h1>
        <form data-ajax="false" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
            <input type = "hidden" name = "p" value = "5">
            <div><input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Save"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

essentialy I needed to add data-ajax="false" to each form, which from what I gather makes it load the page in full. It will only work with method="POST", but as the code shows, its a minor change.

The code here creates 5 expandable boxes ready for form elements, when the save button is clicked, the form is submitted to itself and the expandable box that sent it is triggered to become expanded and active.

If this will present issues in future please comment about it but otherwise i'm overjoyed it goes round.

Comment: Use Ajax. No need to repeat yourself. Read more about pagecontainer events in order to know when do jQM functions/methods work.